# Same background size for differents screen devices

Tags: android, kotlin, background, android-jetpack-compose

I am making an app in android studio using kotlin and jetpack compose. I would like to set an image as background that does NOT fit each device screen, so it maintains the same appearance whether on a device with a resolution of, for example, with 1235x2345 (tablet) or 1080x1920 (smartphone):

[image]

Until now, the image background warp when adjusting to different devices.

### Correct image background (smartphone)

[image]

### Warp image background (tablet)

[image]

As you can see, on tablet the image background doesn't look good... I am using a .jpg as background, is that is the problem, what image format should I use?

Comment: What you are looking for is probably a property called aspect ratio - in Jetpack Compose you can use `Modifier.aspectRatio()` for setting that on a composable. However, you can also have a look at the possibility to provide alternative resources based on some device configuration - it might be better to not use the same static image for all the different devices. As per the file format, on of JPG drawbacks is that it does not contain transparency info - for that you could use PNG or WEBP.

Comment: Hi @Manveru! I think that with your answer I will be able to create an image with a lower resolution that is less heavy for the application. What I did in the end was create the background in Photoshop with a 4K resolution (much larger than any mobile or tablet), I created a box with `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` and within it I created the Image with `Modifier.matchParentSize()` and `ContentScale.None` in such a way that the image exceeds the margins of the phone. I take into account creating several images with different sizes for when the application is more advanced. Thanks for your help!!